# Compare two maps of Collections and filter out the same values

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to compare two maps currMap and prevMap and merge the result to the new one.
By comparing i need to filter out the keys and then values Person.getName() and Person.getSurname(). If prevMap already has the same Person.getName() and Person.getSurname() as currMap, these Collection wont be merged. For example:

```
    // {[Long: 1] : [[name:John, surname: Smith, age: 20, gender: m]]
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> currMap;

   // {[Long: 1] : [[name:John, surname: Smith, age: 20, gender: m],
   //               [name: Sarah, surname: Smith, age:27, gender: f]]
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> prevMap;

// {[Long: 1] : [[name: Sarah, surname: Smith, age:27, gender: f]]
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> result;
```

I tried to do it like that.

```
Collection<Person> arr = new ArrayList();

for (Map.Entry<Long, Collection<Person>> currEntry : currMap.entrySet()) {
            for (Map.Entry<Long, Collection<Person>> prevEntry : prevMap.entrySet()) {

                for (Person currPerson : currEntry.getValue()) {
                    for (Person prevPerson : prevEntry.getValue()) {
                        if((!currPerson.getName().equals(prevPerson.getName()) 
                                && !currPerson.getSurname().equals(prevPerson.getSurname()))) {
                            arr.add(currPerson);
                            result.put(currEntry.getKey(), arr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

return result;
```

I believe there is more efficient way to make it easier through streams. Any tips will be appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: Have you ever programmed with Kotlin?  It makes Java's functional feature  easier (less verbose) to work with.  Sometimes, if I want to do something functional in Java, I try it first in a more functional language (eg Kotlin, Clojure), where there's less noise.  Once I see it work, it's a little easier to implement in Java.  Good luck!

Comment: I once did a HashMap merge function.  It was easier to write as a recursive function.  Lucky for me, the HashMaps were not very deep.  So it was safe to run the recursive function in production.

Comment: Your example and explanation on how you want to "merge" these *maps* is ambiguous, redundancies of the code-snippet obscure what it's intended to do, and it doesn't seem to be aligned with the example. Please, **clarify which entries** you need to preserve? What if *people* having the same *name/surname* are mapped to different *keys* in these maps, should they be discarded? And what if such objects exist only within one of the maps (but not present in another)?

Comment: In other words, are namesake people could appear within **one** map only once (if no, what is the policy for that case)? And does a *person* with a particular name should appear **only once** in the *resulting map*, regardless to which key it would be mapped?

Comment: I don't get why you have maps not sets. The key of prev is completely ignored. I would suggest implementing Comparable on Person. Then you can sort and work with pointers reducing the complexity from O(n * m) to O(nlogn + mlogm). Also with retainAll (need to implement equals correctly) you can get the intersection but not the opposite for that you would need removeIf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a better solution than 4 nested loops:

```
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> currMap = new HashMap<>();
    currMap.put(1L, Arrays.asList(new Person("John", "Smith", 20, 'm')));
    
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> prevMap = new HashMap<>();
    prevMap.put(1L, Arrays.asList(new Person("John", "Smith", 20, 'm'), new Person("Sarah", "Smith", 27, 'f')));
    
    //Merge maps
    Map<Long, Collection<Person>> result = Stream.of(currMap, prevMap)
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey, 
                            Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (value1, value2) -> {
                                //you need to create duplicate collection, because removeAll modify collection 
                                Collection<Person> list1 = new ArrayList<>(value1);
                                Collection<Person> list2 = new ArrayList<>(value2);
  
                                //remove duplicates from collections
                                list1.removeIf(x -> value2.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getName().equals(x.getName()) && p.getSurname().equals(x.getSurname()))); // second from first
                                list2.removeIf(x -> value1.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getName().equals(x.getName()) && p.getSurname().equals(x.getSurname()))); // first from second
                                  
                                Collection<Person> valueOfDuplicateKeys = new ArrayList<>(list1);
                                valueOfDuplicateKeys.addAll(list2);
                                
                                return valueOfDuplicateKeys;
                            }
                    ));
```

ouput:

K: 1
V: [[name=Sarah, surname=Smith, age=27, gender=f]]